# flutter create a button with 2 icons

Tags: flutter

[[image: Elevated button with icon and arrow1]

I can create a button with an icon using this code

```
 ElevatedButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.home,
            color: Colors.green,
            size: 30.0,
          ),
          label: Text('Elevated Button'),
          onPressed: () {
            print('Button Pressed');
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

but how to put an arrow on the right side of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your shared Image I have try same design in Various ways choice is yours which way you want to try.

#### Using ElevatedButton.icon

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.mail,
              color: Colors.green,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
            label: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: const [
                Text('Change Email Address'),
                Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)
              ],
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print('Button Pressed');
            },
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              foregroundColor: Colors.black,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              fixedSize: const Size(double.infinity, 40),
            ),
          ),
```

Result Using [`ElevatedButton.icon`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/ElevatedButton.icon.html) -> [image]

#### Using OutlinedButton.icon

```
OutlinedButton.icon(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.mail,
              color: Colors.green,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
            label: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: const [
                Text(
                  'Change Email Address',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                )
              ],
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print('Button Pressed');
            },
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
             side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black,),
              fixedSize: const Size(double.infinity, 40),
            ),
          ),
```

Result Using [`OutlinedButton.icon`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlinedButton/OutlinedButton.icon.html) -> [image]

#### Using ListTile

```
 ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              print('Button Pressed');
            },
            visualDensity: const VisualDensity(horizontal: -4,vertical: -4),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            leading: const Icon(Icons.mail,color: Colors.green),
            trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
            title: const Text('Change Email Address'),
          ),
```

Result Using [`ListTile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) -> [image: image3]

#### Using GestureDetector

```
 GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('Button Pressed');
            },
            child: Container(
              padding:const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),),
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  Icon(Icons.mail, color: Colors.green),
                  SizedBox(width: 10,),
                  Text('Change Email Address'),
                  Spacer(),
                  Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Result Using [`GestureDetector`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) -> [image: image4]

#### Using InkWell

```
InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print('Button Pressed');
            },
            child: Container(
              padding:const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),),
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  Icon(Icons.mail, color: Colors.green),
                  SizedBox(width: 10,),
                  Text('Change Email Address'),
                  Spacer(),
                  Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Result Using [`InkWell`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html)-> [image: image5]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want a [`ListTile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) widget, as it has `leading`/`trailing` properties:

[image]

```dart
 Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 1,
          ),
        ),
        child: const ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.mail),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
          title: Text('Change Email Address'),
        ),
      )
```

You can also use `IconButton` instead of a regular `Icon` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

To add two icons to an elevated button, just wrap your child widget with a row widget. See implementation below:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: const [
      Icon(Icons.home),
      Text('Home'),
      Icon(Icons.navigate_next)
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image: Elevated Button with Two Icons]